# react app sending request to localhost using proxy

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios

I have a react app running on 'localhost:3000' and a server written in java springboot running on the same computer 'localhost:8080'. I want to send requests from react app to the server using Axios.

The server expects requests like: `GET localhost:8080/list?userid=3`

I tried to send directly (without proxying) by which `baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080'`

This is the request function:

```
function request(username, setData) {
  alert(username);
  axios({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    url: "/list",
    method: "get",
    params: {
      userid: 3,
    },
  })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setData(res.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert("Get item list unsuccessful");
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

It will give me CORS error.

So I fixed it by using `http-proxy-middleware`, this is my `src/setupProxy.js`, and `baseURL = "/"` this time.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function (app) {
  app.use(
    "/",
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: "http://localhost:8080",
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

It's not giving CORS, but showing 404 error this time:
[image: error message]

This is how the server side looks like: it's not giving any response so I assume it's not the problem in server, and it's actually not receiving any request?
[image: springboot server terminal]

I don't know which step is causing this error, any suggestion please.

Thanks.

Comment: The request is going to `3000` .... so it is giving `404`

Comment: @KcH Thanks for your comment. I saw in online tutorial to put target address in `target` when using http-proxy-middleware, is my code in setupProxy.js causing problem? Thanks

Comment: can you keep the `baseURL` static and see in `axios` ...

Comment: @KcH Do you mean `baseURL: "http://localhost:8080"` in the request function? This one will give CORS error

Comment: yes with same proxy set up, giving `baseURL` as "http://localhost:8080" also did you add "proxy": "http://localhost:8080" in `package.json` - was referring to a video :)

Comment: @KcH having `baseURL = "localhost:8080"` and in request() `baseURL = baseURL` will now give 'AxiosError: {message: Unsupported protocol localhost: '. The proxy in package.json doesn't affect anything

Comment: add as `http://localhost:8000` ... sorry while using quotes its ripping off the `http` ...

Comment: So with `baseURL = "http://localhost:8080"` will give CORS error, seems this approach is not using proxy anymore

Comment: did you add in `package.json` too ?

Comment: having and not having in `package.json` seems not affecting the result

Comment: Hey looks like similar issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73943644/11737596