# I am creating a simple website and the proxy URL is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, proxy

I am creating a simple website and the proxy URL is not working. My react app has port number 3000 and nodejs server has port number 8000. But the nodejs server API URL is not coming.

[image: proxy url]

**Why is this shown as port number 3000?**

[image: console error]

here is my Axios req

```js
  const handleSignIn = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(loginStart());
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(`/auth/signin`, {
        email,
        password,
      });
      console.log(res.data);
      dispatch(loginSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(loginFailure());
    }
  };
```

Comment: Are you using the express js server?

Comment: yes. i'm using express server,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define which request you want to do proxy. It's trying to check the URL in your react js project not forwarding to nodejs. If you using external configuration you can use following.

```
proxy: {
  '/api/**': {
    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api',
  },
}
```

Express server you must use http-proxy-middleware to achieve that. Final configuration must look like following.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api/**', {
  target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api',
}));
```

In Axios request, you should use `/api/auth/signin`.

Comment: hi, thank you for the help. now I'm facing this error. POST http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Comment: To check the status code 431 issue you need to check request headers. It may be Too many cookies, The referrer URL is too long, and The total size of request headers is too large.